Complex conjugates in orthonormal basis.
Okay, hello, I am not from the algebra world so I'm sorry for any mistakes. So, assume that we have given some orthonormal vectors $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ in the matrix $A$. We now consider a complex conjugate transpose of $A$ i.e. $A^* $. Okay, so my question is: if we multiply $A^*$ by $e_k$ do we get vector with zeros and $1$ on $k$-th place? I don't know how we get zeros if we consider scalar product of complex conjugate. I am really sorry for any imprecision.

I'm assuming you're working with the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $B := (v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ is a arbitrary orthonormal basis that form the rows of A. This implies that $A$ is unitary and therefore $A^* = A^{-1}$. Furthermore, $A$ is just a transformation matrix from $B$ to $B_0$ $T(B,B_0)$ and therefore $A^{-1} = A^* = T(B_0,B)$. This means that $A^*$ applied to $v_k$ transforms $v_k$ to the corresponding vector in the standard basis $B_0$, yielding $A^*v_k = (0,...,0,1,0,...,0)^T$ where 1 is at the kth entry.

We have -by- matrix whose columns are $e_1,\ldots,e_m$ that are orthonormal. Beyond that, can you tell me why we have this implication that A is unitary? And what is $B_0$? Nevertheless thank You very much for your answer.

The coordinates of $A^*e_k$ are equal $\langle e_i,e_k\rangle,$ $1\le i\le m.$ In general $A^*A=I_m.$ You should add that $n\ge m.$
